# Nestjs conditioning start server after api check

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, health-check

I would start my nestjs server only after a check of an external API (with something like a getHealth check), and start the server only if the check is OK (return code 200).

But i don't know how to handle this check before the server starting.

Comment: I guess you should be able to do that in `bootstrap` function. If the exception will be thrown the app should not start

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you know nest application usually is started with `bootstrap` function. The function may look something like this inside `main.ts` file:

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  await app.listen(3000);
}
```

What you need to do is apply your custom validation logic. It could be anything (also external API request). So from high level point of view your `main.ts` file will look like this:

```
async function applyCustomValidationLogicOrThrow() {
  // apply your logic
  throw new Error('ERROR');
}

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  await applyCustomValidationLogicOrThrow();

  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

If the error will be thrown the app will not start as you wanted, so feel free to use `HttpService` to make a request and validate it